# Laravel how to call variable passed to url in the next page

Tags: php, laravel

My url now has the value I need which is `/search/{$nombor}`. How do I call this variable in the next page?
For example, the url is `/search/3` and I want to print 3 in the next page.

Here is my code

**web.php**

```
route::get('/search',[searchController::class, 'search'])->name('web.search');
route::get('/search/{nombor}',[searchController::class, 'daftar'])->name('web.daftar');
```

**searchController.php**

```
class searchController extends Controller
{
    function daftar($nombor){
        return view('dahDaftar', compact ('nombor'));
    }
}
```

**search.blade.php**

```
<td>
    <a href="search/{{ $nama->nombor }}">DAFTAR</a>
</td>
```

**dahDaftar.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <hr>*PRINT HERE*</hr>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please give us your laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print it out using the same method you've used for the `{{ $nama->nombor }}`, so:

```
{{ $nombor }}
```